Getting the Display Version of the current computer with Powershell7 (I.E.: 22H2). But ReleaseId conflicts with DisplayVersion
I've read a bunch of threads on here about this and I want to get the Windows edition (22H2 for instance).
This is the code:
$ReleaseID = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId
$DisplayVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').DisplayVersion
$ReleaseID
$DisplayVersion

$ReleaseID outputs 2009
$DisplayVersion outputs 22H2
Why is $ReleaseID outputing 2009? What is this number?


Why is $ReleaseID outputting 2009?

You are running Windows 10 22H2. It is a depreciated value that is no longer used. You should instead be looking at CurrentBuild or CurrentBuildNumber.

Registry Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

What is this number?

$ReleasedID would be set to 2009 even if you were running Windows 11 24H2. It's nothing

I'm not looking for the build number. I'm looking for the edition. (22H2 / 24H2 / Etc). I guess I'll just use HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion and DisplayVersion

@fmotion1 - I apologize if my answer does not answer your question. However, you only asked two questions, and I answered both. The only clue you were looking for, DisplayVersion, was written in a way where you used the phrase "for instance" as an example.  However, you ended up only asking about ReleaseId, but editing your question at this point would invalidate my answer. I spent more than an hour and a half installing Windows 10 and Windows 11 to a VM to write my answer.
